# Checking validity of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've written a program that finds the first $K$ eigenvectors of a matrix and would like to figure out if my solutions are truly valid eigenvectors.  What is a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, multiply them on the left by the matrix, divide elementwise, and see if every resulting quotient is the same (within some numerical tolerance).

In other words, be sure that $Ax-\lambda x = 0$.